# VS 2010 crashed on Windows 7 Ultimate N SP1

Tags: windows-7, crash, visual-studio-2010

I've been using Visual Studio (VS) 2010 since it came out, and never had problems with it.

A few months ago I got a new computer with Windows 7 Ultimate N SP1 on it, VS 2010 was working fine for a while, but now it crashes 2-3 times a day with the same error (see below).

The only other difference I can point out is that my new computer has SSD (Solid State Drive).

Any ideas?

p.s.: ran memtest 86+ for 60 hours, no memory errors.

[image]

Event log:

[image]

Comment: Have you run a complete memory test? I'd recommend memtest. This is a memory access violation quite often caused by bad memory. I usually run memtest on new systems for 12 hours before trying to use it. At least let it run for 2 passes.

Comment: Bad ram, bad cpu, bad cache, bad power supply, bad traces on the motherboard...

Comment: This question is *not too localized*, please don't close it for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know when it worked and when it didn't, I think the chance on memory problems are low.

You could still check them but I think it's unlikely that the cause would be there...

---

Can you check the event log (or the details) for the location of a dump file? Can you upload this?

`0xC0000005` is an Access Violation, which means some memory can't be accessed.

In order to know what memory can't be accessed we need to know what the application was doing at that moment, both you and the dump file could help to get more detail on this so we can find the cause...

---

One thing I can think of is that it could be related to Intellisense indexing.

Comment: memtest didn't find any memory problems, i'll upload the dump file if i find it

Comment: event log screenshot posted

Comment: Hmm, so no dump file. Have you tried to completely remove Visual Studio and reinstall it?